# Getting SQL results with inner query

Tags: sql, inner-query

I am having a problem with a SQL query:

```
select 
    o.orderID,c.city 
from 
    `order` o, `customer` c, `ordered_items` oi 
where 
    o.FKCustomerID = c.customerID 
    and o.orderStatus = 'IN PROGRESS' 
    and o.orderID = oi.FKOrderID 
    and (select FKDepartmentID 
         from ordered_items 
         where orderedItemsID in (select orderedItemsID 
                                  from ordered_items 
                                  where FKOrderID = o.orderID) 
           and FKDepartmentID = 11)
order by 
    c.city asc
```

It gives me an error saying, nested query returns more then one row.

What I want to using that nested query is this,

[image]

In the table order id: 819-DBD-EB8-0E7 has 3 items. I want to get that **order no only if all the ordered items are in department ID 11. (FKDepartmentID=11)**

So there is 3 items for that order and all items are in department 11. So that order should be retrieved. If there is only 2 items in that department it should not be retrieved.

How to get that using sql query? In my query other part except inner query is ok.

Need to correct the inner query.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the condition you are trying to fulfill the same as saying that you want that order no only if there *isn't* a linked item whose Department ID is *not* 11?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN yes thats wht I want

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  Although that will not fix this problem, it will fix future problems before they arise.

The solution to your query is to use `group by`.  Then count the number of departments that are *not* 11 -- and take only the orders where that count is 0.

```
select o.orderID, c.city 
from `order` o join
     `customer` c
     on o.FKCustomerID = c.customerID  join
     `ordered_items` oi 
     on o.orderID = oi.FKOrderID
where o.orderStatus = 'IN PROGRESS' 
group by o.order_id, c.city
having sum(FKDepartmentID <> 11) = 0
order by c.city asc ;
```

Note:  Your syntax suggests that you are using MySQL.  The more general `having` clause is:

```
having sum(case when FKDepartmentID <> 11 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: getting an error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`ordered_items` oi 
     on o.orderID = oi.FKOrderID
where o.orderStatus = 'IN P' at line 5

Comment: Thanks, It works now .it should be corrected like this : group by o.orderID

Answer (score 0):

```
and 
(select FKDepartmentID from ordered_items where orderedItemsID in
(select orderedItemsID from ordered_items where FKOrderID=o.orderID)  
  and                              
FKDepartmentID=11)
order by c.city asc
```

This inner query comes in your where condition which does not really make sense. That is because WHERE clause checks if a condition if true or not. You are returning a table with this select subquery and makes no sense.
You probably want to do something like this:
You want to check if orders corrsponding to dept 11 exist or not.
You can do it like this using the EXISTS clause in sql:

```
select o.orderID,c.city 
from `order` o,`customer` c,`ordered_items` oi 
where o.FKCustomerID=c.customerID 
and 
o.orderStatus='IN PROGRESS' 
and 
o.orderID=oi.FKOrderID 
and 
EXISTS (select orderedItemsID from ordered_items where FKOrderID=o.orderID and FKDepartmentID=11)
order by c.city asc
```

Comment: Im getting the order nos now. but need to get the order nos when all order items are in department 11. so if a single item is in another department (like 10) it should not be selected by the query. I checked your answer  and when I changed a  one item to another department from department 11 it also giving the order id. can you help me to correct the query?